# Highcharts animation with color blending

Tags: animation, highcharts, series

Is it possible with High Charts to blend/dissolve the colors in an animation when data changes?
The motion is already working but the barcolors won't blend/dissolve.

Answer (score 0):

Unforuantely defualty it is not possible, you can configurare your animation only by http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.animation . In other cases you need to prepare your own animation mechanism, including edit a source code of highcharts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will build my own solution with jQuery and css to get this done.